# Merge the 'answering-questions' meta-tag into simply 'answers'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There are currently two meta-tags: [answers](/questions/tagged/answers) and [answering-questions](/questions/tagged/answering-questions).

Shouldn't the latter be merged into the former?

The former is more standard, and there's no useful difference between the two.

Comment: I'm waiting to see if anyone jumps up to say "No, there is a difference!" before taking action.

Comment: [This was the first one](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/488/2703) so I guess the tag was invented by Fabian and then other follows suit, reusing that now-existing tag -- so, maybe you'd like to ping/ask Fabian about it.

Comment: Okay. @Fabian? :-)

Comment: @Oddthinking Shall I go ahead and make the edit; or will you; or is there a reason not to do that edit?

Comment: Mods have a tool to help. I have no idea if Trusted Users also can use it, so I just went ahead.

Comment: There's currently only one Trusted User on this site, i.e. Oliver_C, though DJClayworth will become one pretty soon. But I don't think even a Trusted User has that tool.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I went and [read the rules](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). I said "Trusted User" (i.e. 20K rep) but meant "access to moderator tools" (10K). But "Suggest Tag Synonyms" is only 2.5K rep; I *think* that is the same tool (but I don't need to wait for 4 other votes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I merged and created a synonym. <strike>Anyone typing in [answering-questions](/questions/tagged/answering-questions) will now get [answering](/questions/tagged/answering) instead.</strike>

Update: Now anyone typing in  [answering-questions](/questions/tagged/answering-questions) OR [answering](/questions/tagged/answering) will get [answers](/questions/tagged/answers)

Comment: wait, the request was to merge in to [meta-tag:answers], not [meta-tag:answering]. We now have both...

Comment: Yes that wasn't a helpful edit (because now we still have two sets).

Comment: Dammit. There was at least one marked with [tag:answers] already. That must have confused me. Sigh. Fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Besides that [we still have two tags](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3043/merge-the-answering-questions-meta-tag-into-simply-answers#comment9520_3059), I've the following doubg.

Should [asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions) equally go to [questions](/questions/tagged/questions)?

Comment: When a new (empty) meta-site is created it's pre-populated with the most popular tags from http://meta.stackexchange.com/ -- looking at the tag wiki of the tags on http://meta.stackexchange.com/ I think that the 'asking-questions' tag ("This tag is for questions specifically about the process of asking questions on a Stack Exchange site.") is for questions which would belong on http://meta.stackexchange.com/ e.g. because it's about how to use the site software.

Comment: Conversely if the content of the topic is specific to Skeptics then the tag should be 'questions' ("For questions regarding the nature of a "question" on StackExchange sites; e.g. how to ask, whether specific questions are appropriate, etc.")

Comment: @ChrisW not the most popular, but a basic set, yes. We need them because we do cross site tag queries behind the scenes.

Comment: [**We started with all the page 1 tags on meta.so**, the most mature meta site, and pared out anything meta.so specific.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63019/139866)

Comment: That set has been fixed since 2010, it is not a dynamic query.

Comment: Anyway, did I answer your question about 'asking-questions': did you understand and agree with my answer? Did you understand the principle behind it, i.e. to read the tag wiki on meta.so? And would you fix what Oddthinking did with the answering tag?